# Trouble with PRIME configuration on Nvidia Optimus Laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I have a laptop with two graphics cards: An integrated Intel card, and a discrete Nvidia one. I could never get bumblebee to work properly, but the new Nvidia drivers (I am running version 340) have built-in Optimus support, so I have been trying to configure that according to [this](http://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/) post.

Unfortunately, the modesetting driver is really not working for me. Specifically, this error shows up in my Xorg.0.log:

```
[   141.976] (EE) modeset(G1): drmSetMaster failed: Invalid argument
```

For those of you who are curious, [this](https://gist.github.com/djpetti/cea9fa260d433600449b) is my Xorg log file, and [this](https://gist.github.com/djpetti/31a64b8f763b81d005f3) is the xorg.conf file I am using.

I've researched this a lot and have found nothing useful, so I'd appreciate it if someone could at least point me in the right direction.

Oh, and I am running Ubuntu 15.04.